# Create Button ArrayList Kotlin and select boxes

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, kotlin

I am building tic tac toe game. As the player wins game the winned boxes should get difference color.For this I have winned boxes numbers in array `[1,2,3]` or `[4,5,6]`.
My boxes in activity_main.xml named `box1,box2,box3...box9`.
I want to choose boxes dynamically with help of `[1,2,3]` or etc.
I created array list like below,but with this codes app is not opening.
How can I create button arraylist or is there any way to change 3 box colors dynamically with help of array - `[1,2,3]`

```
    var boxes:ArrayList<Button> = arrayListOf(
        findViewById(R.id.box1),
        findViewById(R.id.box2),
        findViewById(R.id.box3),
        findViewById(R.id.box4),
        findViewById(R.id.box5),
        findViewById(R.id.box6),
        findViewById(R.id.box7),
        findViewById(R.id.box8),
        findViewById(R.id.box9)
)
```

Comment: `this codes app is not opening.` have you tried reading the Logcat so you know what the actual error / exception is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this list in your activity:

```
var boxes: ArrayList<Button> = arrayListOf()
```

and in `onCreate` add this:

```
    boxes = arrayListOf(
        findViewById(R.id.box1),
        findViewById(R.id.box2),
        findViewById(R.id.box3),
        findViewById(R.id.box4),
        findViewById(R.id.box5),
        findViewById(R.id.box6),
        findViewById(R.id.box7),
        findViewById(R.id.box8),
        findViewById(R.id.box9)
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making it `lazy`? Currently you are trying to find views before they are created.

```
val boxes by lazy { 
    listOf(
        findViewById(R.id.box1),
        findViewById(R.id.box2),
        findViewById(R.id.box3),
        findViewById(R.id.box4),
        findViewById(R.id.box5),
        findViewById(R.id.box6),
        findViewById(R.id.box7),
        findViewById(R.id.box8),
        findViewById(R.id.box9)
    )
}
```